# Elevation value (in meters) from SRTM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, srtm

How do I determine elevetion/terrain height value from SRTM data?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to provide more details like what you have tried, please?  You may also want to take the [Tour] and review [How to frame a good question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question)

Comment: The elevation is stored as the value of each pixel. Since this is rather trivial I suspect you meant to ask something else with your question?

Answer (score 4):

SRTM data are distributed in a few common formats including *.hgt files, the DTED format, and the more common *.tif file format. Both of these are raster formats and the elevation values are stored directly in each pixel of the raster grid. You see the 'Z' value in the image below that displays as you move your cursor across the image. Each pixel contains an integer value that represents the elevation of the centre point of the grid cell in metres. In the case of the image below, my cursor was overtop of a pixel where the location had an elevation of 248 m. Generally when you import an SRTM TIFF file the data will be stored as 16-bit greyscale image, again each pixel contains the raw elevation value in metres. I realize that this can be confusing because TIFF files are generally used to store image data such as satellite images, where the pixels are often directly related to colour values. As a word of encouragement, never mind the down votes; people often forget how challenging the things that may seem very obvious to those with experience can be to people who are new to a discipline. But as a word of advice for future questions, question posters are generally expected to demonstrate some prior research on the topic on the part of the poster. I hope that helps and good luck with your SRTM processing.

[image]

Comment: SRTM is also distributed in DTED format

Comment: @Vince That's a good point, I'll update my answer to reflect that. I must admit that I tend to not use the DTED format often.

Comment: The easiest way to know is if you have Google Earth of where your area is.. Look at that area and see if they have the elevation numbers...For example if it says 2000 meters then if the SRTM has the same number then it is meters...if the numbers shows like 4000 feet then it is feet..I would look around first and find out and compare between the two...that is the only way to know..